# Error opening Sofi Money Account

Tags: banking, bank-account, online-banking

When trying to open a SoFi money account (or SoFi investment account), I'm told that there was an error and they couldn't verify my identity... i have checked this information 10 times and know its correct so that isn't the problem.

I tried checking my credit score in the SoFi app to see if that would atleast work, but i get this message

> According to TransUnion®, you've recently tried to enroll in this product or a similar one too many times.

> To protect your information, TransUnion® limits repeat enrollment attempts. Please wait 30 days and then retry.

I just turned 18 a week ago and have never tried to "enroll" in any transunion services, I also (i would assume) dont have a credit history considering ive never made any payments on credit.

I did try to open an ally bank account a week ago, but had the same difficulty verifying my identity problem, Im not sure if that has anything to do with this but figured i should add it just incase.

I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar problem or if anyone has a suggestion on how to fix these errors because my parents and I are quite confused.

p.s. I tried calling SoFi, but they said to contact experian, I did and they said i didnt have any credit history, but i dont understamd what that has to do with my identity.

Comment: I Googled "experian contact number" and the number popped right up.

Comment: The real issue is that Experian probably doesn't have anything on you.  Stick with your local bank, and try and get a secured credit card; that will build up a file on you.

Comment: @RonJohn Does credit history really matter for verifying my identity?

Comment: Yup.  This is one reason why you should not listen to anti-CC Dave Ramesy.

Comment: @RonJohn Aha yeah i don't listen to that guy, even though he was basically all we got in my highschool personal finance class. I was just confused because i didnt know how to build a credit history without making a bank account and getting a credit card, but I'm currently opening one with discover and its seeming to work so i can build my credit history there for now. This is all quite daunting to get into for the first time!

Comment: DR says *some* right things, and CC *very well can* lead you to ruin.  (I was **deep** in CC debt for *decades*, until we -- former wife and I -- finally decided to get our act together; we divorced debt-free, paying off our CCs in full at the end of every month.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they said to contact experian, I did and they said i didnt have any credit history, but i dont understamd what that has to do with my identity.

Credit history is how companies (**especially** online companies) determine your identity.  They need to do this because of [Know Your Customer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_your_customer).

> The know your customer or know your client (KYC) guidelines in financial services require that professionals make an effort to verify the identity, suitability, and risks involved with maintaining a business relationship. The procedures fit within the broader scope of a bank's **anti-money laundering** (AML) policy. KYC processes are also employed by companies of all sizes for the purpose of ensuring their proposed customers, agents, consultants, or distributors are anti-bribery compliant, and are **actually who they claim to be**. Banks, insurers, export creditors, and other financial institutions are increasingly demanding that customers provide detailed due diligence information. Initially, these regulations were imposed only on the financial institutions but **now the non-financial industry, fintech**, virtual assets dealers, and even non-profit organizations are **liable to oblige**.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up for me!